# What type of cleats to get for these mtn bike shoes

Tags: mountain-bike, shoes, cleat

Please forgive the beginner question, but I have a pair of old mountain bike shoes that are missing cleats. Can someone point me in the right direction of an example of what to get (on Amazon or elsewhere)? Here is what the bottom of the shoes look like:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Standard MTB mounts (but only one pair of threads will be used), but the exact answer will depends on the pedals, so better that you add a picture of the pedals as well.

Comment: @Renaud thanks! I have added a picture of the pedals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the two pictures, the answer is quite straightforward: Shimano SPD cleats (not SPD SL, that is for road pedals). The Shimano references are SM-SH51 or SM-SH56. Some other brands are doing compatible cleats as well.